# How to connect a local app to Kafka on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster with an instance of Kafka. I'm planning to run an app inside such a cluster.

I'd like to develop this app locally. In other words, my local app needs to connect to Kafka on k8. I tried to forward port 9092 which is Kafka's broker port and I did the same with Schema Registry. But when I try to create a simple topic locally referring to my Kafka on K8, to test the connection I receive the following (below) which gives me an understanding that the connection doesn't work.

And the app seems to be not connected either.

Why it doesn't work?
How to make it work?
What I'm doing wrongly?

I'd appreciate your help with that.

```
2022-01-06 00:40:41,256] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node kafka-1.kafka.confluent.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 1 rack: 1) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-1.kafka.confluent.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known

               at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)

               at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)

               at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)

               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)

               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)

               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:109)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:508)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:465)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:170)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:975)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:301)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.sendEligibleCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:1117)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1377)

               at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1320)

               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: have you gone through  this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aO2pv8W6oZU&ab_channel=Devoxx

Comment: Your advertised listeners are wrong if port forward isn't working. I suggest you use the Strimzi operator add read its docs on external load balancer provisioning

Comment: If you port forwarded to your local laptop, then the java process would connect to `localhost:<portusedforforwarding>` not the DNS name that only resolves within the cluster

Comment: @lance.johnsn yes, but (as I understand why it's not working in this way) is that then the local app is not able to connect to brokers. It's because kafka instance for which I'll do port forward refers to their addresses inside a k8 cluster. Plus, you never know which one is a Leader.